# Textfield controller method makes performance slow down

Tags: performance, gridview, dart, flutter, onchange

I'm filtering my list of my GridView.builder like this:

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {

if (text.isEmpty) {
  _searchList = _productList.toList();
  setState(() {
  });
  return;
}


_searchList = _productList.where((product) => product.name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
    product.type.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList();

setState(() {});
```

}

but when im typing on the textfield the performance just go down, exactly to 2.5 fps sometimes when im deleting the text or typing to fast.

This is my Gridview builder

```
GridView.builder(
        primary: false,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: itemWidth / itemHeight,
        ),
        itemCount: _searchList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _searchList[index];
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Always set state variables inside the setState() call.

Make your onSearchTextChanged() function save the search text and start a Future.delayed() that performs the search and update after a short delay.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686588/1736338 .

You can use a [Suffix Tree](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/suffix.htm) data structure to speed up the search operation.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find one written in Dartlang.  You could code one.  The [trie](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/trie) package is unsuitable since it supports only Set functionality, not Map functionality.